# Suggestion on beginning Enterpise Java Beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

As I face a couple problems on my beginning in `EJB` technology leading frequently to awkward   and time consuming situations, I am considering ordering a book focused exclusively (or predominantly) on `Enterprise Java Beans`. I want necessarily the book to deal with `CDI`, because it is the most powerful contemporary aspect of the technology. Which book would you recommend, which covers my last request and not to be constrained on the basics but going in depth in the potential of the technology?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following 2 books:

[EJB 3.1 Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849682380), [Java EE 6 Pocket Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144933668X)

And I see a new book at Manning, it is due in summer 2013:

[EJB 3 in Action, Second Edition](http://www.manning.com/panda2/)

Comment: After a quick glance at the contents of the first book, I realized it does not contain a capital pertaining to CDI.

Comment: That's why the Java EE 6 Pocket Guide. I suggest not either of them but both of them. :)